# How to set Object type tag into list view?

Tags: android

I’m using android list fragment,following is my adapter class

```
private class HugStatusAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Status> {
………….
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

………..
//set tag to view(type Status is bean class)
convertView.setTag(getItem(position));

}
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
// how to get the tag (Status) and put it into  mBundle
}
}
```

my question is how to set object(Status) type tag into view and get that tag from onListItemClick() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already setting a `Status` object as the tag. You just have to cast it back later, i.e.:

```
public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int pos, long id) {
    Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    Status status = (Status)v.getTag();
    mBundle.putParcelable("status", status);
}
```

IMPORTANTLY, for the above to work, your `Status` class *must* implement `Parcelable`. There's a good example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/321697).